# Camera couldn't rotate along a spiral path

Tags: camera, path

today I have a new problem with the camera movement. (It seems I bump into problems every day)
I tried to make the camera push towards the main object(in the file you will see it's a medal in our game) while rotating as it moves along. I created an empty cube, parented the camera with it, added a "follow path" modifier with the spiral path along which the camera would move, and added a "track to" modifier and set the target to the main object. After the configuration, the camera could move but I couldn't make it rotate no matter where I clicked. Then I created a new file, repeated the process and guess what, now the camera can rotate but I can't stop the rotation. I am confused. I've attached both files, please point out where I did wrong and what I should do, thanks in advance!

[image: medal animation.blend]

[medal animation.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8osplp1jeymkrmt/medal%20animatioin.blend?dl=0)

[the other .blend file that made me confused](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d374n5bh665t0ux/camera_move_practise.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

For the file with the spiral, disable the *Follow Path* constraint's "Fixed Position"* option and click on the *Animate Path* button:

[image]

If you want to go from top to bottom, select your spiral, switch to *Edit* mode, as you can see if you display the normals they go from bottom to top, so select all and right click > *Switch Direction*.

[image]